Wireshark Lua: Sending http POST requests using Lua in Wireshark
I am trying but failing to send http POST requests using Lua in Wireshark. My approach is to use the socket.http and ltn12 Lua modules, however, I do not know how to have Wireshark load these modules into its Lua base correctly.
I am simply just adding the following lines to a Lua file which Wireshark reads on program boot up:
 local http = require("socket.http")
 local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

The error I receive is:
module 'socket.http' not found:\n\tno field package.preload['socket.http']\n\tno file 

Obviously, I am missing some source socket.http (and ltn12) module files but do not know how to include them or what files they should be.
Thank you for any help.
